# Set background of layout from Uri

Tags: android

I return an Uri when I select an image from the gallery. I want to set this image as the background of my layout. If it was an ImageView, it would be fine. How can I do it?

```
    case LOAD_FROM_GALLERY: 
        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        //ImageView.setImageURI(mImageCaptureUri);

        mylayout.??

        break;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below

```
Uri path = data.getData();
ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
iv.setImageURI(path);
```

Edit:

```
    Uri path = data.getData();
```

Then call

```
    File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(path));  
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
myalyout.setBackground(d);
```

getRealPathFromURI method

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                return contentURI.getPath();
            } else { 
                cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
                return cursor.getString(idx); 
            }
        }
```

Example:

activtiy_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="106dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout rl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getImage();
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void  getImage()
    {
        // To open up a gallery browser
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
        // To handle when an image is selected from the browser, add the following to your Activity
    }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
        // currImageURI is the global variable I�m using to hold the content:// URI of the image
        Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
        File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

        if (file.exists()) {

            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
            rl.setBackground(d);
        }
        }
        }
        }
        private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                return contentURI.getPath();
            } else { 
                cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
                return cursor.getString(idx); 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: use setBackground(drawable)

Comment: Yeah, I found it, thanks. In the meantime I managed to do it with an imageview as well, but the image is squeezed to fit the screen. Is there any way to e.g. display the center of the image and cut off the edges so the image would be shown nicely in the layout or imageview?

Comment: any idea please

Comment: @Rodrigo depends on the os verison you may need to use fileprovider on m and above i guess

Answer (score 0):

look here, this should give You the right direction...

http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.de/2011/05/pick-image-from-gallery-set-to-image.html

Comment: Like I said, I have a layout, not an imageview

Comment: ok, then I have understand Your statement "If it was an ImageView, it would be fine" wrong. Then please show Your layout xml to let us know where You want to set the image.

Comment: Why? It's a normal relativelayout that consists of objects. So if I were able to set the image as bg of the layout then the whole screen of phone's screen would be that image.

Comment: but how we were able to know that? There is too less information in Your question. Anyway, usualy to set image as background to a layout You should call yourLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resource); or yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawble);

Comment: @erdomester use this `mylayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d)` or `mylayout.setBackground(d)` based on the min api. one of the methods is deprecated